# Show a text file's every line in combobox,edit and save back only the changed part

Tags: c#, csv, text, combobox, edit

I have a text file like this:

```
0124456, 10000,2
0124434, 10001,1
0126234, 10002,2
```

It has about 60-70 rows. I would want to add "0124456" , "0124434" and "0126234" to combobox items. I could only do this with richtextbox. It was showing every line until "," line by line but when i saved it it was saving back only the "0124456" , "0124434" and "0126234" line by line and got rid of "10000,2" etc.

My save code looks like this:

```
        SaveFileDialog svf = new SaveFileDialog();
        svf.Filter = "Text files (.csv)|*.csv";
        svf.Title = "Save file...";
        if (svf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(svf.FileName);
            string[] lines = richTextBox1.Text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                sw.Write(line, Environment.NewLine);
            }
            richTextBox1.Clear();
            sw.Close();
        } 
//and my open-read code is this:
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "Text files (.csv)|*.csv";
        ofd.Title = "Open a file...";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ofd.FileName);
            string currentLine;
            while ((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (currentLine == null)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    string[] adat = currentLine.Split(',');
                    richTextBox1.AppendText(adat[0] + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
            sr.Close();
        }
```

So my purpose would be to open csv file and add the first "words" to combobox items and after i edit them i save back only the edited "word".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi your issue is with in the opening of file as you are showing only first part in the rich text box and that is what being saved back

```
richTextBox1.AppendText(adat[0] + Environment.NewLine);
```

if you want to save all the lines ,you have to show them all.

Comment: If i show all the text in richtextbox can i add only the first words to combobox items? and save them back to richtextbox and then the text file?

Comment: i want to understand few thing ,is rich text box visible and user allow to change values how drop down is being used ? ,yes you can show value ins drop down using adat[0]

Comment: Anyways i solved it. I showed all the text in rich text box and added the words to combobox item with TextReader method via Split.